# Como puedo obtener numero entero literal de mas de 18 digits

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

Llevo mucho tiempo consultando como puedo obtener un valor literalmente entero en `javascript` cuando este valor es o supera 16 digits, entiendo que `Javascript` usa algun tipo de estandar para manejar estos numeros pero no he encontrado una solución...

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente:
tengo un valor en un `input` de 9999999999999999 este valor tiene 16 caracteres, pero Javascript me lo coloca como 10000000000000000, existe alguna librería que permita manejar el numero literalmente y el tipo de datos? o como puedo solucionarlo

```js
var numero = 9999999999999999;
var numero2 = 999999999999999;
console.log("Numero literalmente valor y tipo de datos con 15 digitos:" + numero2);
console.log("Numero redondeado por javascript con 16 digitos:" + numero)
```

Answer (score 3):

Para ello deberías usar BigInt

Además de mostrar el número como cadena.

```js
const n = BigInt("99999999999999999999");
console.log(n.toString());
```

Comment: Si lo agrego como string luego no me va permitir crear operaciones...

Comment: Estaba buscando la info para que indages el resto -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Los valores BigInt no son "strings", son objetos de tipo "BigInt".
Para realizar operaciones, debes indicar que los números son del mismo tipo, añadiendo una 'n' al final, por ejemplo 12345678901234567890n * 200n. Añadir el "toString" es solo para mostrarlo sin la n final.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Que pasaría si quiero hacer una operacion 9999999999999999999999.89 + 10, y quiero que me salga 9999999999999999999999.99, no se puede hacer con BigInt()

Comment: @zerokita, claro porque BigInt solo gestiona números enteros.
Si quieres trabajar con decimales, te aconsejo quitar la palabra "enteros" del título, y añadir un ejemplo de lo que buscas con decimales.